# How to create label on chart containing contents from a cell on another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Simple problem.  I have a chart in Excel and some text data on a sheet.  I want to create labels on the chart that reference text on another sheet.  I want to be able to update the text and have the labels on the chart be in sync.

Is this possible?  I don't think its directly supported and we might have to add the text as "series" and turn on data labels.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it was really simple.

Just create a textbox on the chart and then in the formula bar reference the cell you want.

I problem was I was trying to type the formula into the textbox!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
Sheet 1 - A1 cell: 10  
Sheet 2 - A1 cell: =Sheet1!A1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with the chart title as well - select it, click in the formula bar, add a formula as usual
This might be just a link to a cell eg =A1, or w hole complicate thing, or some concatenated text like ="Sales figures for "&A1&" region, "&B1&" to "&C1